# Trigger timer after collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am trying to make the game where the timer is triggered after the collision with one of the characters. I struggle to make the right code for that. Here is what I have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject textDisplay;
  public int secondsLeft = 30;
  public bool takingAway = false;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) instead of Start?
{
 if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
 {
textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "00:" + secondsLeft = true;
 }

void Start(){
  textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "00:" + secondsLeft;
}

void Update()
{
  if (takingAway == false && secondsLeft > 0)
  {
    StartCoroutine(TimerTake());
  }
}

IEnumerator TimerTake()
{
  takingAway = true;
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
  secondsLeft -= 1;
  textDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "00:" + secondsLeft;
  takingAway = false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying is:

- every second reduce one second
- if the player collides stop the timer

I would probably do it somewhat like this

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // directly give your field the correct type
    public Text textDisplay;
    public int secondsLeft = 30;

    // Optionally add some events to be invoked 
    // these are like the onClick of Buttons

    // This event is invoked when the player didn't reach in time
    public UnityEvent whenTimedOut;
    // This event is invoked when the player stopped the timer
    public UnityEvent whenStoppedByPlayer;

    // If return type is IEnumerator Unity runs Start 
    // automatically as Coroutine
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {   
        while(secondsLeft > 0)
        {
            textDisplay.text = "00:" + secondsLeft;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            secondsLeft --;     
        }

        textDisplay.text = "00:" + secondsLeft;
        whenTimedOut.Invoke();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            // by disabling this component also the Coroutine is stoppepd
            enabled = false;
            textDisplay.text = "00:" + secondsLeft;
  
            whenStoppedByPlayer.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or are you trying to start the timer **after** a player triggered it? In this case you could directly run this also as a Coroutine like e.g.

```
private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) yield break;
    
    while(secondsLeft > 0)
    {
        textDisplay.text = "00:" + secondsLeft;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        secondsLeft--;
    }
    
    textDisplay.text = "00:" + secondsLeft;

    whenTimedOut.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to start the timer after a player triggered it. Thank you so much! This is the final code I have used:

Comment: `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour{


      public Text textDisplay;
      public int secondsLeft = 30;

      private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
      {
    if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) yield break;

    while(secondsLeft > 0)
    {
        textDisplay.text = "00:" + secondsLeft;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        secondsLeft--;
    }

    textDisplay.text = "00:" + secondsLeft;

      }
    
}`